# login with facebook redirect to blank page laravel socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

after i set up a facebook log in with laravel socialite instead of redirect to home page i get blank page

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
            'name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday', 'avatar'
        ])->scopes([
            'email'
        ])->redirect('home');


    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        dd($user);
        return  redirect()->route('job_seeker/jobs');[enter image description here][1]
    }
```

ps:i get redirect to blank page after the image below

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Most of the time you can view your Laravel log in `storage/logs` to see what error occured

Comment: @kerbholz i can't find any errors

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have `dd($user);` in your `handleProviderCallback()` method? If so, that method is killing the function call and never gets to the `return redirect()` line. Remove the `dd()` and things should work as expected.

Comment: While true, there should be `dd` output on the page, not a blank page.

Comment: No, because the `dd` output is happening on the server, it hasn't redirected back to the app yet to display anything.

Comment: OP states "ps:i get redirect to blank page after the image below". After clicking "Continue as Moussa", Facebook redirects back to the redirect URL provided by Socialite, which should be the `handleProviderCallback` route, which is presumably where the blank page is.

Comment: but i get nothing in dd i get just blank page